# Инициализация свойств класса

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Как можно проинициализировать свойства класса?
Количество свойств и их имена неизвестны, единственное, что у каждого свойства есть атрибут примерно такого вида:

```
[CustomAttribute(Field="Name", Type=String)]
public string UserName {get;set;}
```

По сути мне нужно вычитать данные из хранилища (lucene index). Список полей, которые необходимо вычитать, получаю из атрибутов. На этом этапе проблем нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть, есть класс с заранее неизвестным списком свойств, у каждого из которых есть некий атрибут. И надо каждому из этих свойств присвоить некое значение. Можно действовать в такой последовательности.

1. Получить список свойств класса с помощью вызова `typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties()`.
2. Для каждого свойства получить атрибут с помощью вызова `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute()`.
3. Исходя из логики вашего приложения присвоить свойству значение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.